# Is there a way to get PHAssetResource for array of PHAsset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

I'm trying to get all `PHAsset` from the library. However, when getting them, we need to get the `PHAssetResource` to get the `fileSize`.

When we have a small number of images, the array is returned in less than 30 seconds; however, when we have around 12k~ image, it's taking too long.

Is there any way to load the resources for all the assets by one call instead of calling the API several times ?

Example:

```
NSArray<PHAssetResource *> *const assetResources = [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset: asset];
if (![assetResources firstObject]) {
  return;
}

[resource valueForKey:@"fileSize"]
```

PS: I don't mind a solution in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way. You always have to first get the PHAsset then query the PHAssetResources for this asset.
In theory there would be a way (the iOS Photo Library is CoreData database), but Apple has not included any API to make such a query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This means that when the Photo Gallery grows, there are no ways of getting the images in a `faster` way ? In galleries around 21k~ it's taking around 5 minutes.

Comment: Only the methods that return PHFetchResult (e.g. fetchAssets) do scale as they load the database objects, when they are actually accessed.